# LLVM with CUDA inline assembly

Tags: c++, cuda, llvm-clang

I am trying to compile a CUDA code with following inline assembly:

```
static __device__ uint get_smid(void) {
    uint ret;
    asm("mov.u32 %0, %smid;" : "=r"(ret) );
    return ret;
}
```

The code compiles fine with `nvcc` with a flag `-Xptxas -v`.

When i try to compile it with `clang++` (version 4.0), with corresponding flag `-Xcuda-ptxas -v` (I think this is right, but I maybe mistaken), I get following error:

> `../../include/cutil_subset.h:23:25: error: invalid % escape in inline assembly string
>        asm("mov.u32 %0, %smid;" : "=r"(ret) );`

It points to `%smid`.

I think I am suppose to link proper library but I have this too: `L/cuda/install/lib`.

Another possibility is NVPTX asm incompatibility. On this [page](http://llvm.org/docs/NVPTXUsage.html#id20), it is explained that LLVM has different definitions for all PTX variables (there are some for smid and warpid as well). Now I am lost if the mentioned code has to be separately (not inline) written and compiled as such.

Has anybody dealt with similar issue before? Suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: I don't have the toolchain set up atm to verify, but I suspect you need to reference the special register with a double percent sign: `%%smid`. That escape sequence gets converted to a singe percent sign during compilation, so that ptxas sees the correct special register name. 

The double percent sign version also works under nvcc. It seems to be an nvcc extension that it leaves unknown escape sequences untouched rather than emitting an error.

Comment: Oh yeah, tera I am sorry that I did not update this one!! You are right!! I solved it few days ago and totally forgot about this question I posted earlier. Thank you for replying anyway. Please add this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to reference the special register with a double percent sign: `%%smid`.

The `%%` escape sequence gets converted to a single percent sign during compilation, so that ptxas sees the correct special register name. The double percent sign version also works under nvcc.

`nvcc` seems to be more forgiving with escape sequences in inline assembler than `clang++` is, and leaves unknown escape sequences untouched rather than emitting an error as clang does in this case.